# Transaction from suprnova to local gui wallet failed

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, payment-id, transaction-failed

over the weekend I installed the newest XMR gui wallet (windows 10) and imported my old (2014) wallet file into it. Daemon synced over the weekend, all looked good.

Yesterday night I decided to cash out mining proceeds from suprnova and sent these to my local wallet address. 15 hours later, it still hadn't appeared. Ocminer was nice enough to credit the failed cash-out transaction back to my pool account, but I am still at a loss in regards to what happened.

Why didn't that transaction go through? I'm mining on nanopool as well currently and would hate to have the same happen to me there. Is my old wallet not compatible anymore? Have I done something wrong? Should I have generated a payment ID in the wallet before I sent a cash out request on suprnova?

Would appreciate any help on the matter!

Many thanks
Mike

Answer (score 1):

A transaction may fail to make it into the chain for various reasons:

- it might be intrinsically invalid in some way: for example, the signatures being incorrect, or using a ring size smaller than the network minimum
- it might be double spending an output already on the chain: this can happen if a transaction is dropped from a daemon, which then accepts another spending one of the original inputs, but other daemons might mine the first one in the meantime
- it might stay more than a day in the txpool, in which case it'll be dropped due to age: if the tx was valid, it could be because its fee was too small and there was non stop contention by other txes.

If you got a transaction hash for that missing transaction, you can check whether it's on the chain by looking it up on a block explorer, for instance moneroblocks.info. If it is there, then it was not really missing, and it could be a bug in the wallet, or the wallet wasn't up to date. Or it could have been mined later than the time you deemed it to be missing.

Comment: All sorted now! Needed to clear the cache of the wallet. Deleted wallet.bin, re-ran and whoosh, here they were! Ocminer reimbursed, happy days.